# Dividing Python properties to categories

Tags: python, properties

I have a class which contains a large amount of properties. More specifically, the class represents my router.
I want to divide its properties to categories, meaning that in order to retrieve the LAN ip and the WAN ip I would not have to type:

```
router.wan_ip
router.lan_ip
```

But instead type:

```
router.wan.ip
router.lan.ip
```

The properties are dynamic and retrieved when calling their functions. My current implementation:

```
class Category(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._parent = parent

class Lan(Category):
    @property
    def ip(self):
        self._parent._get_property("lanip")

class Wan(Category):
    @property
    def ip(self):
        self._parent._get_property("wanip")

class Router(object):
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.lan = Lan(self)
        self.wan = Wan(self)

    def _get_property(self, property_name):
        # Some code here
```

But I wounder if there is a better way

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? What specifically would make an alternate solution "better"?

Comment: I think that the two-way relationship between the categories and the parent class, which is made by giving the categories the instance of their parent, is not such a good OOP practice. Am I wrong?

Comment: `_get_property` should not exist. Just use regular Python properties and `__getattr__` for that.

Comment: Your solution is simple and obvious, doesn't require any advanced knowledge, and does meet your requirements. In which way do you think it could be "better" ?  The only point is that you have a circular reference that may keep your Router instances alive for longer than strictly required, which may or not be a problem depending on client code and execution context.

Comment: Also, personally, if the `Router` object is going to be the one storing the property values, I'd stick with the underscores. I'm not sure what value you gain by overengineering this. (Alternately, have `Wan` and `Lan` store the property values, and work around `Router` not having them all.)

Comment: @millimoose: "The properties are dynamic and retrieved when calling their functions". We don't have all implementation details here but I assume splitting the implementation of `_get_property` might not be that obvious.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I suppose I'm assuming a huge `if..elsif..else` block going off the property name then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably overthinking this structure, but if you want objects...

`Wan` and `Lan` should not exist. You can pass a prefix for the `Category` class so it will search for `...ip`. The `_get_property` method could be replaced by a dictionary. If you need to calculate the values on the fly, you may create a `dict` with functions to be called.

```
class Category(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, prefix):
        self.parent = parent
        self.prefix = prefix
    @property
    def ip(self):
        self.parent.data[self.prefix + "ip"]

class Router(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.lan = Category(self, 'lan')
        self.wan = Category(self, 'wan')
        self.data = data
```

By the way, this program doesn't need to have any class at all. Seems like you just need dictionaries. You can create a function to build these dictionaries if needed

```
router = {'wan': {'ip': '1.2.3.4'}, 'lan': {'ip': '2.3.4.5'}}
```

Comment: Having Lan and Wan as classes allow to have categories with different attributes set - some "categories" may not have an "ip" property, and may have properties that makes no sense for a Wan or Lan.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Then make a **single** subclass of `Category` for those. That's the point

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) that will allow you to access properties that don't really exist by that name, by examining the name of the property, and mapping it to an actual property.

Comment: Having properties that do "exist by that name" makes introspection easier so better to use descriptors than `__getattr__` whenever possible. Also, using `__getattr__` in this case would require to return category instances since "router.wan.id" would resolve to `router.__getattr__('wan').__getattr__('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use descriptors [1] for an unique Category class.

[1] http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors